# Criar banco no servidor por meio de modelo (.mwb) mysql-workbench via linha de comando

Tags: modelo-relacional, batch, mysql, linha-de-comando

Estou tentando montar um bat para criar o banco de dados no servido do mysql a partir de um modelo EER (.mwb) do mysql-workbench, ou seja, em linha de comando, é possível realizar este processo? Alguém poderia dar uma luz?

**Edição:**

Abrindo ele no cmd tenho o seguinte:

```
MySQLWorkbench [<options>] [<name of a model file or sql script>]
Options:
  --query [<connection>|<connection string>]
                          Open a query tab and ask for connection if nothing is specified.
                          If named connection is specified it will be opened,
                          else connection will be created based on the given connection string,
                          which should be in form <user>@<host>:<port>
  --admin <instance>      Open a administration tab to the named instance
  --upgrade-mysql-dbs     Open a migration wizard tab
  --model <model file>    Open the given EER model file
  --script <sql file>     Open the given SQL file in an connection, best in conjunction 
                          with a query parameter
  --run-script <file>     Execute Python code from a file
  --run <code>            Execute the given Python code
  --run-python <code>     Execute the given Python code
  --migration             Open the Migration Wizard tab
  --quit-when-done        Quit Workbench when the script is done
  --log-to-stderr         Also log to stderr
  --help, -h              Show command line options and exit
  --log-level=<level>     Valid levels are: error, warning, info, debug1, debug2, debug3
  --verbose, -v           Enable diagnostics output
  --version               Show Workbench version number and exit
  --open <file>           Open the given file at startup (deprecated, use script, model etc.)
```

Então poderia usar --model mais o --run-script e depois o --quit-when-done, mas nesse caso como seria esse script, em que linguagem?Alguma dica de como escrever-lo?

**Edição 2**

Encontrei uma pergunta igual no SO em inglês, realmente parece não haver uma forma de fazer isso.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556330/command-line-foward-engineering-using-a-mwb-file

**Edição 3**

É claro que existe resposta, depois de pesquisar coloquei ela ai em baixo caso alguém precise.

Comment: Na documentação do MySQL Workbench tem alguns exemplos de uso do scripts em Python: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-scripting-shell.html. E também este link, do time de desenvolvimento do workbench: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-scripting-shell.html. Reparei que apesar do workbench aceitar parâmetros na linha de comando, este não roda em linha de comando apenas em modo gráfico.

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr vou dar uma olhada, mas se realmente não tiver como gastei meu 50 pontos mas agora tenho certeza que não é possível.

Comment: @Artur_Indio mostrei que é possível e como chegar lá se ainda precisar de ajuda em como tratar o arquivo xml ou como montar um arquivo bat ou sh para automatizar o dump para dentro do mysql abre outra pergunta para não ficar amplo demais

Comment: Galera eu consegui fazer, realmente é necessário o código python, e o cara de onde peguei botou até o github o código, tinha até usado uma vez mas pensava que estava utilizando a metodologia proposta por @SneepSNinjA, ai quando fui olhar a fonte tava lá o código python o tempo todo. Vou esperar ai mais alguém tentar responder, se não ao fim do bount coloco minha resposta mesmo sem valer nada só para ajudar os outros. Valeu pela ajuda de todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então depois de muito pesquisar eu consegui fazer o bat, realmente o script para ser usado era em python, tive que aprender um pouco de python. Sei que não posso responder minha própria reposta que está com recompensa, mas como não obtive uma resposta satisfatória vou colocar-la aqui e também para ajudar caso alguém precise. Segue as linhas principais, você pode customizar e criar um bat com argumentos e outras coisas dependendo de sua linguagem preferencial. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 6.1.7\MySQLWorkbench.exe" -model "C:\ModelosERR.mwb" -run-python "import os;import grt;from grt.modules import DbMySQLFE as MySQLFE;c = grt.root.wb.doc.physicalModels[0].catalog;MySQLFE.generateSQLCreateStatements(c, c.version, {});MySQLFE.createScriptForCatalogObjects(r'C:\temp.sql', c, {})" -quit-when-done

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql.exe" -u root -proot < "C:\temp.sql"
```

Answer (score 3):

Vou te dar o caminho das pedras, mas não vou escrever aqui o arquivo .bat inteiro não.

1. o arquivo.mwb é um arquivo compactado, renomeia ele para .zip e descomopacta ele.
2. procure pelo arquivo .xml e abra ele em um editor de texto

Dentro desse arquivo tem todas as marcações de Tag's necessárias para construir o seu .sql que na sequência fazer o dump para dentro do mysql.

Então sim tem como, e não, eu não vou manipular esse arquivo, você escolhe a melhor técnica e aplique em cima desse arquivo xml, faz replace na mão, usa php xml to array, faz com json, da seu jeito, vou deixar o exemplo de como fica o arquivo mwb depois de descompactado:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<data grt_format="2.0" document_type="MySQL Workbench Model" version="1.4.4">
  <value type="object" struct-name="workbench.Document" id="{A6AEAF1F-556E-433D-9483-5253F37D41EE}" struct-checksum="0x7131bf99">
    <value type="object" struct-name="workbench.logical.Model" id="{3183BE53-D18E-4B6F-AD8A-AE08B7BD19A2}" struct-checksum="0xf4220370" key="logicalModel">
      <value _ptr_="0B831168" type="list" content-type="object" content-struct-name="workbench.logical.Diagram" key="diagrams"/>
      <value _ptr_="0B8313E8" type="dict" key="customData"/>
      <value _ptr_="0B832C98" type="list" content-type="object" content-struct-name="model.Marker" key="markers"/>
      <value _ptr_="0B8308F8" type="dict" key="options"/>
      <value type="string" key="name"></value>
      <link type="object" struct-name="GrtObject" key="owner">{A6AEAF1F-556E-433D-9483-5253F37D41EE}</link>
    </value>
    <value _ptr_="0B831348" type="list" content-type="object" content-struct-name="workbench.OverviewPanel" key="overviewPanels"/>
    <value _ptr_="0B830E98" type="list" content-type="object" content-struct-name="workbench.physical.Model" key="physicalModels">
      <value type="object" struct-name="workbench.physical.Model" id="{2E273679-67EA-48F4-A08F-92A272B4D13F}" struct-checksum="0x5f896d18">
        <value type="object" struct-name="db.mysql.Catalog" id="{ECE8278F-2DB8-4352-B627-6552022356F5}" struct-checksum="0x82ad3466" key="catalog">
          <value _ptr_="0B831398" type="list" content-type="object" content-struct-name="db.mysql.LogFileGroup" key="logFileGroups"/>
          <value _ptr_="0B830858" type="list" content-type="object" content-struct-name="db.mysql.Schema" key="schemata">
            <value type="object" struct-name="db.mysql.Schema" id="{5278BE8F-6DD9-4F97-978C-C55DFCEE2B47}" struct-checksum="0x20b94c22">
              <value _ptr_="0B8312F8" type="list" content-type="object" content-struct-name="db.mysql.RoutineGroup" key="routineGroups"/>
              <value _ptr_="0B831C58" type="list" content-type="object" content-struct-name="db.mysql.Routine" key="routines">
                <value type="object" struct-name="db.mysql.Routine" id="{7BB0B591-6EA6-409B-8F04-24B8E9076FA4}" struct-checksum="0x991f611c">
                  <value _ptr_="0B8318E8" type="list" content-type="object" content-struct-name="db.mysql.RoutineParam" key="params">
                    <value type="object" struct-name="db.mysql.RoutineParam" id="{C7FBF5C3-B6D8-43F5-9927-68FCC119125F}" struct-checksum="0x3f238dee">
                      <value type="string" key="datatype">INT</value>
                      <value type="string" key="paramType">IN</value>
                      <value type="string" key="name">cpf</value>
                      <link type="object" struct-name="GrtObject" key="owner">{7BB0B591-6EA6-409B-8F04-24B8E9076FA4}</link>
                    </value>
                  </value>
                  <value type="string" key="returnDatatype"></value>
                  <value type="string" key="security"></value>
                  <value type="string" key="name">duplicadoCpf</value>
                  <value type="string" key="routineType">procedure</value>
                  <value type="int" key="sequenceNumber">0</value>
                  <value type="string" key="definer">marcio`@`%</value>
                  <value type="string" key="sqlBody">BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000'
    BEGIN
    SELECT 'CPF CADASTRADO PARA OUTRO MOTORISTA' AS Msg;
    END;
    INSERT INTO tab_proprietario SET prop_cpf = cpf;
    END</value>
                  <value type="string" key="sqlDefinition">

CREATE DEFINER=`marcio`@`%` PROCEDURE `duplicadoCpf`(IN cpf INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000'
    BEGIN
    SELECT 'CPF CADASTRADO PARA OUTRO MOTORISTA' AS Msg;
    END;
    INSERT INTO tab_proprietario SET prop_cpf = cpf;
    END</value>
                  <value type="int" key="commentedOut">0</value>
                  <value type="string" key="createDate">2013-04-17 09:17</value>
                  <value _ptr_="0B831578" type="dict" key="customData"/>
                  <value type="string" key="lastChangeDate">2013-09-05 08:06</value>
                  <value type="int" key="modelOnly">0</value>
                  <link type="object" struct-name="GrtNamedObject" key="owner">{5278BE8F-6DD9-4F97-978C-C55DFCEE2B47}</link>
                  <value type="string" key="temp_sql"></value>
                  <value type="string" key="comment"></value>
                  <value type="string" key="oldName">duplicadoCpf</value>
                </value>
.
.
.
```

Boa sorte!

> E aqui a citação da fonte dar crédito a quem merece https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956525/how-to-convert-mwb-into-sql-without-workbench

Comment: @Artur_Indio se você usa o workbench então a resposta do EdgarMunizBerlinck esta certa já tem ferramentas (gráficas) para isso, se quer usar linha de comando minha resposta ou esse seu link ai resolve, não ficou claro o que precisa ainda ( pelo menos  para mim)

Comment: Na minha pergunta eu boto "Então poderia usar --model mais o --run-script e depois o --quit-when-done, mas nesse caso como seria esse script, em que linguagem?Alguma dica de como escrever-lo?", seria o código utilizado no --run-script, provavelmente em python.

Comment: Consegui, mas mesmo assim muito obrigado, agora sei que o arquivo mwb é um zip com xml, vlw.

Answer (score 1):

Minha resposta talvez não seja satisfatória pra você. Trabalho com o MySql Workbench desde o beta e nunca vi algo assim. Acredito que isso nem seja possível.

Algo que costumo usar é o Sincronize Model, que pega o seu mwb e o compara com o banco de dados da conexão que você selecionou. Isso é útil tanto para replicar alteração quanto para criar todo o modelo do zero.

Caso tenho alguma dúvida sobre esse processo comente aqui que eu explico melhor.

Agora é possível executar um arquivo sql usando o cli do mysql, então você precisaria exportar seu mwb para um arquivo sql.

Comment: Justamente não queria realizar esse passo em exportar para sql, queria jogar o mwb no servidor e lá no processo em bat ou outro criar o banco no servidor mysql. Mas se não é possível via linha então gastei meu 50 pontos.

Comment: Mas pq você não conecta ao servidor pelo workbench e faz isso que te falei?

Comment: Ah, e talvez seja possível. Eu pelo menos nunca vi esse tipo de coisa.

Comment: Realmente tive que fazer o forward engineering e jogar no mysql via código, que coloquei ai em cima, vlw pela ajuda.